# Parse JSON Array in Postman

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, postman

I have some Response body data returned from a request made in Postman in the form of a JSON.

Sample:

```
{
    "targets": {
        "@uri": "/api/space/tag-management/tags/98304/targets",
        "target": [
            {
                "@type": "vnd.net.juniper.space.device-management.device",
                "@uri": "/api/space/tag-management/tags/98304/targets/98328",
                "@href": "/api/space/device-management/devices/196657"
            },
            {
                "@type": "vnd.net.juniper.space.device-management.device",
                "@uri": "/api/space/tag-management/tags/98304/targets/98329",
                "@href": "/api/space/device-management/devices/196656"
            },
            {
                "@type": "vnd.net.juniper.space.device-management.device",
                "@uri": "/api/space/tag-management/tags/98304/targets/98330",
                "@href": "/api/space/device-management/devices/196655"
```

I have been trying to get just the Device ID from this data.
Each block is a device.
At the end of @href the number value is the Device ID - /devices/***196655***

I've looked around but don't understand this enough to troubleshoot my problems.

I've tried this block of code:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i <   jsonData.targets.target.length; i++) {
    var counter = jsonData.targets.target[i]['@href'].split(‘/‘);
    results.push(counter[counter.length - 1]);
}

pm.environment.set("DeviceID", results.join(‘,’));
```

UPDATE:

I've found a solution using lodash, but i'm having trouble calling the variable in postman. likely an issue on the client usage (my fault), not the code side.

Here's the code i was able to solve this with.

```
let body = pm.response.json().targets.target,
    ids = _.map(body, (id) => id['@href'].split("/")[5]);

pm.globals.set("DeviceID", ids)
```

After this it puts my data into a global variable just as i needed it to.

[image: Global Variable]

Edit: Here is the new problem i'm getting. 
Postman seems to not recognize my {{DeviceID}} variable call within the body of my next request.

[image: Syntax error - ???DeviceID???]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 2nd line, you are trying to parse json, but line one sets response as json, so line to is unnecessary.

If you use your first block of code, but remove the 2nd line and have your for loop use response, it ought to work.

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i <   jsonData.targets.target.length; i++) {
    var counter = jsonData.targets.target[i][“@href”].split(‘/‘);
    results.push(counter[counter.length - 1]);
}

// use me 
// results.join(‘,’);
```

Comment: If I remove the second line then jsonData is no longer defined.

I renamed the var jsonData but there's still an error:

There was an error in evaluating the test script:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @oo call the response variable jsonData instead. var jsonData = pm.response.json() and change this line: jsonData.targets.target.href.length to jsonData.targets.target.length

Comment: Then change jsonData.targets.target.href[i] to jsonData.targets.target[i].href

Comment: Same thing with that one. :(

Comment: @oo I’ve updated my answer to show more clearly what needs to change.

Comment: @oo I’d missed that counter wasn’t an object but a string value. Counter does not have a property called counter_name.

Comment: :O 
It's no longer giving me an error.
But my console is returning null for every increment. 
null
 
null
 
null
 
null
 
null
 
null
 
null
 
null
 
null
 
null
 
null
 
null

Comment: @oo ok. Now if you look in your postman console you will see a log of the values you are logging.

Comment: oh duh that makes sense. i had to change the double quotes to single quotes but now i'm getting the entire /api/space/device-management/devices/123435 line in my console. I just need to figure out how to cut off the excess and save it in a variable

Comment: @oo which bit of the url do you need?

Comment: Just the integer at the end. i need to append them to a variable delimited by a comma. 1234, 4321, 1111, 2222, 3333, etc

Comment: @oo my answer is updated. Use the comment line at the end to save it in the pm variable. It’s a string so you don’t need to use JSON.stringify, just copy the results.join line into the value parameter of the pm variable set method.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive support. Sadly this is giving me an error - There was an error in evaluating the test script:  SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @oo does it tell you what the unexpected token is?

Comment: Unfortunately not. 

I've copied the entire error message. Not very helpful i know. I've updated my post with the code i have in my test.

Comment: @oo firstly, use the pm.variable.set outside of the loop, if you want to set the entire comma separated list of numbers. After that maybe try removing the -1 from the counter.length -1. I’d do more checks but I’m on my mobile - sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that resolved my issue.

```
let body = pm.response.json().targets.target,
    ids = _.map(body, (id) => id['@href'].split("/")[5]);

pm.globals.set("DeviceID", ids)
```

Had another issue with it not populating the global variable in my body, found out i had an Environment variable and global variable with the same name.

Removed Env var and issue was resolved.